# Can I create a smart contract to spread money between 3 usdt wallets after paying?

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, tether

Can I create a smart contract to spread money between 3 usdt wallets after paying?
for example:

When I send a 300 usdt(tether) to , after that I want my smart contract to give a 150 usdt to  and 150 usdt to .

all of the 300 usdt on the trc20 should be paid.

Can the above scenario be achieved? And is that correct?
**What is the best practice?**

Comment: you can check the paymentsplitter fromopenzeppelin.

Comment: @Nergon , can i create a another smart contract and using another coin in own smart contract?